# Laravel eloquent: Multiply two columns of two different tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

### My Order Model

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','user_id', 'erp_id', 'currency_code','ex_rate_with_base','order_status','status','created_at'
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['updated_at',];

    public function orderList(){
        return $this->hasMany(OrderList::class);
    }   

    public function currency(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class,'currency_code');
    }

}
```

### My Currency Model

```
class Currency extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'currency_code','currency_name', 'currency_symbol', 'ex_rate_with_base', 'update_via', 'status',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at','updated_at','updated_by','created_by',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'currency_code';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class,'currency_code');
    }
}
```

### My OrderList Model

```
class OrderList extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','order_id', 'product_code', 'qty','unit_price','status',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
       'created_at' ,'updated_at',
    ];

    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

---

In my Order controller I want to run the query:

```
$order_history_list = Order::where([['user_id', $user->id], ['updated_at','>', $updated_at]])
    ->with([
        'currency' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('currency_code','currency_symbol','ex_rate_with_base');
        },
        'orderList' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id','order_id', 'product_code', '***order_lists.qty * orders.ex_rate_with_base AS unit_price_with_ex_rate***','status');
        }
    ])->get();
```

But error is occuring due to the highlighted portion.
Error: Unknown column 'order_lists.qty * orders.ex_rate_with_base' in 'field list'
Please help me with the correct syntax
How can I use column of order table in the sub query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DB::raw in your select statement and add a join to the 'orderList' $query

```
    $order_history_list = Order::where([['user_id', $user->id], ['updated_at','>', $updated_at]])
    ->with([
        'currency' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('currency_code','currency_symbol','ex_rate_with_base');
        },
        'orderList' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id','order_id', 'product_code', DB::raw('order_lists.qty * orders.ex_rate_with_base AS unit_price_with_ex_rate'),'status')
                  ->join('orders','order_lists.order_id', 'orders.id');
        }
    ])->get();
```

Comment: I have already tried DB::raw but it didn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you run this code and tell me what error you get?

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_lists.qty' in 'field list'. This is the error I am getting

Comment: Ahh, you probably need to add a join condition.  Check my edit.

Comment: Hey Jed, Thanks it worked .I just needed to modify some fields also.I am posting my final query

Answer (score 1):

### My Final Query That Worked:

```
$order_history_list = Order::where([['user_id',$user->id],['updated_at','>',$updated_at]])
                ->with(['currency'=>function($query){
           $query->select('currency_code','currency_symbol','ex_rate_with_base');
                },'orderList' => function($query){
                    $query->select('order_lists.id','order_lists.order_id', 'order_lists.product_code', 'order_lists.qty','order_lists.unit_price',DB::raw('he_order_lists.qty* he_orders.ex_rate_with_base AS unit_price_with_ex_rate'),'order_lists.status')->join('orders','order_lists.order_id', 'orders.id');
                }])->get();
```